# How to update a record using PUT in AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, sapui5

I am working on an app that uses SAPUI5 to post data to a local SQL DB through OData. The post method is working and it data is being added in the DB. Now i want to update the record using PUT http request but i am encountering the following error. Data in the JSON is being stored in global variable and passed in JSON object

Help would be greatly appreciated.

[Console error report from the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnYKF.png)

```
         $.ajax({  
                      url: 'http://localhost:3466/products('+ID1+')',
                      type : 'PUT',
                      contentType : 'application/json',
                      processData: false,
                      dataType: 'json',

                    data: {
                        "Id":ID1,
                        "Name":Name1,
                        "Cost":Cost1,
                        "Status":Status1,
                        "EmployeeNo":Employee1,
                        "Designation":Designation1,
                        "Destination":Destination1,
                        "PurposeVisit":PurposeVisit1,
                        "BatchNo":BatchNo1,
                        "Modetravel":Modetravel1,
                        "TravelDate":TravelDate1,
                        "DaysNo":DaysNo1,
                        "Stay":Stay1
                    },
```

Comment: you need to send JSON ...so `data: JSON.stringify({
                        "Id":ID1, .... etc}),`

Comment: I am confused here, if you are using OData, why arent you using an OData model? then you could use the update() methode of said model....

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/update

Comment: OR you can use the method **oModel.submitChanges()** for Two-way updates on server and model, if you are working with SAPUI5.